# Linux rar не могу добавить файл в архив

Tags: linux, centos, rar

Есть гайд в котором написано что команда `rar u archive.rar file.tile` позволяет добавить файл в уже существующий архив.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Офф. документация так же говорит про эту команду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь добавить файл в архив выдаёт следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом если я удалю существующий архив и повторю выполнение команды - то он создаться с новым файлом.

Получается что в моём случае команда предназначенная для добавления файла не может этого сделать а только создать новый.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @alexanderbarakin изображение лучше смотрится

Comment: файлы лежат в корне? Они там точно есть?

Comment: @maint да, пробовал вводить имя несуществующего файла там другая ошибка - WARNING: No files

Comment: /test.rar , точно в корне. А судя по картинке (мерзость редкая, текст нужен) все это у вас в /home/www/rar

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась сама после того как я просто перезашёл в консоль и подключился заново на сервер.

Comment: Например, место на диске закончилось (там же написано, что не может создать временный файл, а ошибка *ENOENT*).