# Linux не могу использовать rar

Tags: linux, centos, rar

Есть Centos машина где я установил rar.

Возьмём обычную команду из документации:

```
rar u -sp1 /main/test.rar /main/test.txt
```

В папке пользователя main через которого я подключился к машине создался архив test.rar с файлом test.lol

Но если я повторю попытку и введу ту же команду вот что получится:

```
-bash-4.2$ rar u  -sp1 /main/test.rar /main/test.txt

RAR 5.61   Copyright (c) 1993-2018 Alexander Roshal   30 Sep 2018
Trial version             Type 'rar -?' for help

Evaluation copy. Please register.

Updating archive /main/test.rar

Cannot create __rar_30656.29028
Permission denied
Program aborted
-bash-4.2$
```

То есть грубо говоря я не могу проводить манипуляции уже с существующими архивами и добавлять / переносить в него файлы а мне это нужно.

Папка /main имеет Owner Main с которого я выполняю команды, так-же я поставил права 777 на эту директорию, потом я подумал что может программа  не может создать временный файл архива и сделал chown Main и права 777 ещё и для папки /tmp но это не помогает.

P.S. с root пользователя всё работает.

Права каталога main:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 main root 4096 Nov 28 12:30 /main
```

Место на VPS ещё 14 gb.

Comment: `Cannot create __rar_30656.29028` - не может создать временный файл. Где он создается, не ясно, но похоже, что НЕ в `/tmp`, а в текущем каталоге. В текущем каталоге какие права (`ls -ld .`)?

Comment: Вторая причина - кончилось место. У рута лимит +10%. Свободное место проверяется так: `df -h`

Comment: Права каталога main: drwxrwxrwx 2 main root 4096 Nov 28 12:30 /main Место на VPS ещё 14 gb.

Comment: @TotalPusher да это скорее всего дубликат - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905974/linux-rar-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2?rq=1 сейчас парень подключится заново на сервер и пройдёт. Хотя не знаю, там вроде другая ошибка была, не связана с правами.

Comment: `umask` в студию. чую в этом проблема.

Comment: @turik97 нет, не дубликат, тут другая версия rar :) . Но причина, почему после переподключения проблема решилась - опять же, может быть связана с неправильным использованием `umask`. Я сделал `umask 222`, и проблема ТС проявилась именно так.

Comment: @TotalPusher `-bash-4.2$ umask
0002`

Comment: @TotalPusher `umask` вообще для меня отдельная история, помню долго из-за этого мучился. Вон вам кстати ТС ответил, судя по его аве видимо паренёк ещё и профиль новый создал

Comment: А у root `#umask 0022`

Comment: покажите `ls -la /main/test.rar` и `whoami` после первого создания. варианты кончаются ...

Comment: Вот раз - `-bash-4.2$ ls -la /main/test.rar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 main main 79 Nov 28 15:26 /main/test.rar` вот два `-bash-4.2$ whoami main`

Comment: Вроде всё сходится но так-же не работает.

Comment: Есть подозрение на SElinux. Выполните `sestatus`. Если включен (`enabled`), то `sudo setenforce 0` - выключить временно SElinux, затем попробуйте снова.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо ситуация настолько редкая что даже гуру SO не знают точно что делать.

**Мною найдено альтернативное решение которое хоть как-то работает:**

> Вообщем если манипулировать архивами в папке текущего пользователя, а
>   в моем случае это /home/main/ - то никаких ошибок не возникнет и всё
>   работает.

За этими пределами ситуация та-же. Поставив все права, 777, нужную umask - но всё равно с существующими архивами ничего сделать не удаётся - появляется ошибка доступа и единственное что можно это только создавать новые.

Пускай хотя-бы так пока.

Comment: P.S. в вопросе где - `test.lol` у меня опечатка, на самом деле файл всё тот-же `test.txt`

Comment: Ситуация редкая, так как никто в здравом уме не будет использовать rar на линуксе, это проприетарщина. Тут правит tar.